# Extracting just one value from a z3 model

Tags: string, z3

I'm looking for the z3 source API equivalent of **get-value**. For example, when I have the following query, I can easily specify which values I want to be seen:

```
(declare-const s1 String)
(declare-const s2 String)

(assert (= 8 (str.len     s1         )))
(assert (= 3 (str.indexof s1    "M" 0)))

(assert (=  3 (str.len     s2         )))
(assert (= -1 (str.indexof s2 "\x00" 0)))

(check-sat)
;(get-value (s1))
(get-value (s1 s2))
```

I manage to do the same thing with the (C) source API,
but then I only get **the entire model** (s1 **and** s2) and can't seem
to find how to print **just one of them**:

```
void string_example()
{
    Z3_ast M;
    Z3_ast s1;
    Z3_ast s2;
    Z3_ast x00;
    Z3_ast zero;
    Z3_ast three;
    Z3_ast eight;
    Z3_ast cond1;
    Z3_ast cond2;
    Z3_ast cond3;
    Z3_ast cond4;
    Z3_ast minusOne;
    Z3_ast strlen_s1;
    Z3_ast strlen_s2;
    Z3_ast strchr_s1_M;
    Z3_ast strchr_s2_x00;

    /***************/
    /* [0] Context */
    /***************/
    Z3_context ctx = mk_context();

    /**************/
    /* [1] Solver */
    /**************/
    Z3_solver solver = mk_solver(ctx);

    /*************/
    /* [2] Sorts */
    /*************/
    Z3_sort int_sort   =Z3_mk_int_sort(ctx);
    Z3_sort string_sort=Z3_mk_string_sort(ctx);

    /*********************************/
    /* [3] (declare-const zero  Int) */
    /*     (declare-const eight Int) */
    /*********************************/
    zero    =Z3_mk_int(ctx, 0,int_sort);
    three   =Z3_mk_int(ctx, 3,int_sort);
    eight   =Z3_mk_int(ctx, 8,int_sort);
    minusOne=Z3_mk_int(ctx,-1,int_sort);

    /*********************************/
    /* [4] (declare-const s1 String) */
    /*     (declare-const s2 String) */
    /*********************************/
    s1 = Z3_mk_const(ctx,Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx,"s1"),string_sort);
    s2 = Z3_mk_const(ctx,Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx,"s2"),string_sort);

    /**********************************************/
    /* [5] (assert (= (str.len someStringVar) 8)) */
    /**********************************************/
    strlen_s1 = Z3_mk_seq_length(ctx,s1);
    cond1 = Z3_mk_eq(ctx,strlen_s1,eight);
    Z3_solver_assert(ctx,solver,cond1);

    /*********************************************/
    /* [6] (assert (= (str.indexof s1 "M" 0) 3)) */
    /*********************************************/
    M = Z3_mk_string(ctx,"M");
    strchr_s1_M = Z3_mk_seq_index(ctx,s1,M,zero);
    cond2 = Z3_mk_eq(ctx,strchr_s1_M,three);
    Z3_solver_assert(ctx,solver,cond2);

    /***********************************/
    /* [7] (assert (= (str.len s2) 3)) */
    /***********************************/
    strlen_s2 = Z3_mk_seq_length(ctx,s2);
    cond3 = Z3_mk_eq(ctx,strlen_s2,three);
    Z3_solver_assert(ctx,solver,cond3);

    /*************************************************/
    /* [8] (assert (= (str.indexof s2 "\x00" 0) -1)) */
    /*************************************************/
    x00 = Z3_mk_string(ctx,"\\x00");
    strchr_s2_x00 = Z3_mk_seq_index(ctx,s2,x00,zero);
    cond4 = Z3_mk_eq(ctx,strchr_s2_x00,minusOne);
    Z3_solver_assert(ctx,solver,cond4);

    /*******************/
    /* [9] (check-sat) */
    /*******************/
    if (Z3_solver_check(ctx,solver))
    {
        printf("\nHere are my two strings:\n");
        printf("======================= \n\n");
        printf("%s\n",Z3_model_to_string(ctx,Z3_solver_get_model(ctx, solver)));
    }
    /**********************************/
    /* [10] delete solver and context */
    /**********************************/
    del_solver(ctx, solver);
    Z3_del_context(ctx);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Here are my two strings:
======================= 

s2 -> "\x01\x10\x01"
s1 -> "\x00\x00\x00M\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

EDIT:

When we added the following code, we were able to extract only s1:

```
printf("\nHere is just s1:\n");
printf("================= \n\n");
Z3_model_eval(ctx,Z3_solver_get_model(ctx, solver),s1,1,&out);
printf("%s\n",Z3_get_string(ctx,out));
```

When we added the following code, we were able to extract only s1 by name:

```
printf("\nHere is just s1:\n");
printf("================= \n\n");
Z3_model_eval(ctx,Z3_solver_get_model(ctx, solver),Z3_mk_const(ctx,Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx,"s1"),Z3_mk_string_sort(ctx)),1,&out);
printf("%s\n",Z3_get_string(ctx,out));
```

Comment: Usually, when one solves their own question then one adds the solution in an answer and marks it as accepted, as opposed to editing the question. It might be sensible to use some inline function to make it more readable.. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [Z3_model_eval](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga7dafbd3d8b7663dcc142c11f71e7bbd2) to evaluate any expression of your choice under the model and then to print that expression.

Comment: Thanks! We've managed to do this (question edited) but we wanted to know whether we can extract s1 by name, rather than by its ast?

Comment: Ok we extended our question so that it contains the possibility of extracting the value just from the name ... it works good