# Extracting z3 query with context and solver

Tags: z3, smt

Following the extraction of values from a query, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48908699/extracting-just-one-value-from-a-z3-model),
I encounter something that looks like a bug. How is it possible to print a human readable format of the relevant query, when all I have is the **context** and **the solver**?

I mean, suppose that just before this line is performed, I want to print the query:

```
Z3_solver_check(ctx,solver)
```

I could have used this API:

```
Z3_ast_to_string(Z3_context c, Z3_ast a)
```

But **where is that Z3_ast a**? I mean it's implicit somewhere in the solver, but how can I extract it?
Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Z3_solver_to_string](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#gae8610a38a4a6d7389c57995517011035).